# Which is faster: 2 Insert statement of 175K records each OR 1 statement to insert 350K records in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to insert 350K records using INSERT INTO statement.

```
INSERT INTO xxx ( 5 cols )
SELECT 
    { 5 col names} 
FROM 
    ( 
        This part fetches records using multiple Joins and few condition.
    )
WHERE 
    x_type IN ( 1, 2 );
```

The total records being inserted here are about 350K+.
Would it be good approach to split this in 2 SQL using
with with where condition

```
x_type = 1
```

and another with where condition

```
x_type = 2
```

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I don't think that splitting that up in two queries will change anything.

Comment: why should it be faster?

Comment: Couldn't two smaller transactions be faster than one huge?

Comment: [race your horses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Reasons to split this: - if you anticipate a possible error and only want to rollback a part of the data instead of everything, and/or - you think that transaction log might become too big. Performance? I don't think so